# Is there any method for enumerating an object and then a collection?

Tags: smalltalk

Does any Smalltalk dialect implement something on the lines of

```
Object >> #andThen: aCollection do: aBlock
  self value: aBlock.
  aCollection do: aBlock
```

The reason I'm asking is because this pattern appears here and there and I always spend time pondering whether to create a new collection and then #do:, or whether to inline the code in the client for the sake of efficiency.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of a situation where the element is not in the collection.

You have a list of strings and a title:

```
FOOD
 nuts
 apples
 seeds
 beans
 tomatoes
 algae
 mushrooms
 sprouts
```

and you are trying to do something with them. Let's say you want to calculate the max width, or you want to display them all on screen, etc.

The title does not belong in the collection, but for some of the operations we want to do with them we need to consider both, the title and the items.

Comment: I'd be more curious to know why that object is not part of the collection, as it obviously must have a similar type and must process the same action.

Comment: @MaxLeske thanks for the comment. I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
{ self }, aCollection do: aBlock
```

You could also make this more explicit:

```
(aCollection copyWithFirst: self) do: aBlock
```

Comment: Depending on the type of collection you are using (i.e. growable collections like `OrderedCollection`, you might also consider `(aCollection addFirst: self) do: aBlock`. The difference is of course that you don't create a copy of the collection. Tobias's answer is more generic though.

Comment: @MaxLeske & Tobias. In both cases (say, `Array` and `OrderedCollection`) the code needs to do something else than just evaluating `aBlock` with the element. Much like the joke where the mathematician cools the water and then applies the previous procedure.

Comment: Be aware that `#copyWithFirst:` will have the side effect of modifying the collection, which could be bad in many cases.

Comment: That is not true. The original collection will *not* be modified. The iteration works on a copy of the original collection with an extra slot.

Comment: But then, it has the effect of copying the collection, potentially affecting the performance and generating garbage

Comment: Yes. But generally, most collection methods do: `#collect:`, `#select:`, `#reject:`, `#inject:into:`. You should measure if it is really a problem. I doubt it, though.

Answer (score 1):

The original question asks, "is this a good idea?"
and gives some code.

Yes, it is a good idea, but has a typo.
because the second line thereof is written backwards.

Here's a corrected version.
(Just correcting the typo in the original question).

```
>>andThen: aCollection do: ablock
    ablock value: self.
    ^aCollection do: ablock
```

---

---

Next:

My earlier answer also had a typo.
And needed a better comment.

So here's a corrected version of that one (the answer of 9/11/16).

```
"
 This version also works for
   any combination of parameters,
   and in any order.
" 
>>andThen: anotherObject do: a1block
    self do: a1block.
    ^anotherObject do: a1block
```

Note: The above depends on another definition,
      which may not be present in your image.

Object would also need to define #do:, as follows...

```
Object>>do: a1block
    ^a1block value: self
```

Comment: Ha! You are right. `self value: aBlock` makes no sense. I should had written `aBlock value: self` instead. Good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if Food was the key for a Dictionary entry with its associated collection?

Comment: I'm afraid that would not address the issue as you would still need to evaluate `aBlock` with the key and then with the associated collection, which exactly replicates the pattern I'm trying to capture in one method.

Answer (score 0):

It does now -- thanks.
With a slight change -- to a symmetric implementation

```
>>andThen: anotherObject do: a1block
    self do: a1block.
    ^anotherObject do: aCollection
```